вывод консольной программы в memo
Почему у меня все логи сыпятся в err хотя должны разделяться
type
  TArg<T> = reference to procedure(const Arg: T);

procedure CaptureConsoleOutput(const ACommand, AParameters: String; Log, Err: TArg<PAnsiChar>);
const
  CReadBuffer = 2400;
var
  saSecurity: TSecurityAttributes;
  hRead: THandle;
  hWrite: THandle;
  hError, hWriteErr: THandle;
  suiStartup: TStartupInfo;
  piProcess: TProcessInformation;
  pBuffer: array [0 .. CReadBuffer] of AnsiChar;
  dBuffer: array [0 .. CReadBuffer] of AnsiChar;
  dRead: DWORD;
  dRunning: DWORD;
  dAvailable: DWORD;
  CreationFlags : DWORD;
  ConsoleOutputCP: Cardinal;

begin
  saSecurity.nLength := SizeOf(TSecurityAttributes);
  saSecurity.bInheritHandle := true;
  saSecurity.lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;

  if CreatePipe(hRead, hWrite, @saSecurity, 0) and CreatePipe(hError, hWriteErr, @saSecurity, 0) then
    try
      FillChar(suiStartup, SizeOf(TStartupInfo), #0);
      suiStartup .cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
      suiStartup.hStdInput := hRead;
      suiStartup.hStdOutput := hWrite;
      suiStartup.hStdError := hError;
      suiStartup.dwFlags := STARTF_USESTDHANDLES or STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
      suiStartup.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;

      CreationFlags := CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE or
                       CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE or
                       NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS;

      if CreateProcess(nil, PChar(ACommand + ' ' + AParameters), @saSecurity, @saSecurity, true, CreationFlags, nil, nil, suiStartup, piProcess) then
        try
          CloseHandle(hWrite);
          CloseHandle(hWriteErr);

          repeat
            dRunning := WaitForSingleObject(piProcess.hProcess, 50);

            PeekNamedPipe(hRead, nil, 0, nil, @dAvailable, nil);
            if (dAvailable > 0) then
              repeat
                dRead := 0;
                ReadFile(hRead, pBuffer[0], CReadBuffer, dRead, nil);
                pBuffer[dRead] := #0;
                OemToCharA(pBuffer, dBuffer);
                Log(dBuffer);
              until (dRead < CReadBuffer);

            PeekNamedPipe(hError, nil, 0, nil, @dAvailable, nil);
            if (dAvailable > 0) then
              repeat
                dRead := 0;
                ReadFile(hError, pBuffer[0], CReadBuffer, dRead, nil);
                pBuffer[dRead] := #0;
                OemToCharA(pBuffer, dBuffer);
                Err(dBuffer);
              until (dRead < CReadBuffer);
          until (dRunning <> WAIT_TIMEOUT);
        finally
          CloseHandle(piProcess.hProcess);
          CloseHandle(piProcess.hThread);
        end;
    finally
      CloseHandle(hRead);
      CloseHandle(hWrite);
    end;
end;

а вот так выглядят принимающие процедуры
procedure TForm2.ToMemo(const Line: PAnsiChar);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(String(Line));
  Label1.Caption := IntToStr(Memo1.Lines.Count);
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;

procedure TForm2.ToError(const Line: PAnsiChar);
begin
  Memo2.Lines.Add(String(Line));
  Label2.Caption := IntToStr(Memo2.Lines.Count);
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;

что я делаю не так?
P.S. запускаю ffmpeg.exe

Я удивлён что вообще что-то приходит, ведь конец для записи Err никуда не пришит...

@Alekcvp там получается что в обычный stdout сыплется всё подряд и ошибки и предупреждения и прогресс и всё-всё-всё ((((( Наверное если посмотреть в исходники (в СИ разбираюсь очень поверхностно) наверное там нет разделения. Видимо надо брать весь вывод и фильтровать его
